# Finding the limit of $ \frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n}\sqrt[k]{k} $

Tags: calculus, limits

I need some help regarding a certain section in a homework question. I need to find the limit of:

$ \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\left(\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n}\sqrt[k]{k}\right)$

Now my intuition is that it converges to 1, but the whole question is centered around the number $ e $, so I'm guessing there's some connection to $ e $ and thats where I'm stuck.

Anyone have any hints?

Thanks

Comment: Stick with your intuition.

Comment: If you replace the kth root of k with the asymptotic equivalent 1... Is it legal?

Comment: I am not getting how come this converge to $1$.. atleast intuitively... have you seen anything similar to this before.. what made you to guess like that... please explain a bit more...

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik Estimate $\varepsilon_k = \sqrt[k]{k}-1$. For $k \geqslant 2$, you have $k =(1+\varepsilon_k)^k \geqslant 1 + k\varepsilon_k + \binom{k}{2}\varepsilon_k^2$.

Comment: I understand what you have written but could not relate to the question. excuse me for my dumbness...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

*Hint:* If $a_n\to a$ then $\frac1n\sum_{k=1}^n a_n\to a$ (Cesáro summation)

*Edit:*
If Cesáro cannot be used immediately, here's a quick proof:
As $a_n$ converges, it is bounded, say $|a_n|<M$ for all $n$.
Let $\epsilon>0$ be given. There exists $N$ with $|a_n-a|<\frac\epsilon2$ for all $n>N$. Then $$\left|\frac1n\sum_{k=1}^n a_n -a\right|=\left|\frac1n\sum_{k=1}^n (a_n -a)\right|\le \frac1n\sum_{k=1}^N(M+a)+\frac1n\sum_{k=N+1}^n\frac\epsilon2\le \frac Nn(M+a)+\frac\epsilon2$$
for such $n$.
Now let $N'=\max\left\{N,\left\lceil\frac{2N(M+a)}{\epsilon}\right\rceil\right\}$. Then 
$$\left|\frac1n\sum_{k=1}^n a_n -a\right|<\epsilon$$
for all $n>N'$.

Comment: This is so elegant... I am sure any of the answers would use this idea in some way  or the other ... $\sqrt[k]{k}\rightarrow 1$ So, $\frac{1}{n} \sum _{k=1}^n \sqrt[k]{k} \rightarrow 1$...

Comment: Wow really simple solution, unfortunately we haven't learnt the Cesaro summation yet so I can't use it :(

Comment: I don't think so! $\lim_{n\to \infty}\sqrt[n]{n}\to 1$ but $\lim_{n\to \infty}\sum_{k=1}^n\sqrt[k]{k}\neq n$

Answer (score 2):

For $k\geq N$, then $1<\sqrt[k]{k}<1+\epsilon$. So for $n\geq N$, $$\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=N}^n1<\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=N}^n\sqrt[k]{k}<\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=N}^n(1+\epsilon)$$

which implies

$$\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{N-1}\sqrt[k]{k}+\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=N}^n1<\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n\sqrt[k]{k}<\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{N-1}\sqrt[k]{k}+\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=N}^n(1+\epsilon)$$

$$\frac{A}{n}+\frac{n-N+1}{n}<\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n\sqrt[k]{k}<\frac{A}{n}+\frac{n-N+1}{n}(1+\epsilon)$$

Now you can squeeze.

Answer (score 0):

With Stolz-Cesaro:

$$L=\lim_{n\to \infty}\left ( \frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n}\sqrt[n]{n} \right )=\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{\left ( \sum_{k=1}^{n}\sqrt[k]{k} \right )-\left ( \sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\sqrt[k]{k} \right )}{n-(n-1)}=\lim_{n\to \infty}\sqrt[n]{n}$$

Hence

$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{\ln n}{n}=\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{\ln(n+1)-\ln n}{(n+1)-n}=\lim_{n\to \infty}\ln\left ( 1+\frac{1}{n} \right )=0$$
$$\to\lim_{n\to \infty}\sqrt[n]{n}=1$$

Hence: $L=1$